# Como faço um sistema de cadastro onde o usuário em um primeiro momento informe apenas o e-mail?

Tags: php, jquery

Gostaria de saber como faço para criar um sistema de cadastro onde o usuário em um primeiro momento informe apenas o e-mail, logo após ele será direcionado para outra página, onde irá completar o cadastro com o e-mail já preenchido.

Comment: Bom, você deve primeiro escolher uma  linguagem  de programação a qual deseja tarablhar como php c#(asp.net) java e por ai vai, apos isso também  necessitará de um banco de dados, para amazenar os dados, sua pergunta ficou  muito  generica poderia especifica-la melhor e qual linguage utiliza ?

Comment: Qual linguagem de servidor vc usa? (ex., PHP)

Comment: utilizo a linguagem PHP, o problema não e realizar o cadastro do usuário, primeiro seria exibido ao usuário apenas um input type mail, logo após preencher o e- mail ele será direcionado para outra página para finalizar o seu cadastro.  minha duvida é cmo salvar o e-mail informado é continuar a preencher os dados em outra pagina, onde o campo e-mail já deve está preenchido. AQUI TEM UM EXEMPLO https://www.baratosuplementos.com.br/checkout/

Comment: Acredito que nesse exemplo de site que vc deu @DiegoLima seja para verificar a existencia de algum registro no mesmo email

Comment: Acho que armazenar o email em $_SESSION é uma boa

Answer (score 0):

Como questão de cadastro envolve muitas validações etc., vou apenas abordar os passos básicos que você pode usar.

Funcionaria basicamente da seguinte forma usando 3 páginas:

- `cadastro1.php`

A primeira página onde o usuário informa apenas o e-mail para ir para a página `cadastro2.php`. Nesta página haveria um formulário tal como:

```
<form method="post" action="cadastro2.php">
   <input required type="email" name="email" placeholder="Informe seu e-mail">
   <br>
   <button>Prosseguir</button>
</form>
```

- `cadastro2.php`

Nesta segunda página você vai receber o e-mail informado na primeira página via POST. Nesta página e na terceira, você deve verificar se as informações foram enviadas da página anterior; caso não, você redireciona para a primeira página, porque o usuário pode tentar acessar a página sem passar pela anterior:

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email']; // pego o campo "email" enviado pela primeira página

if(empty($email)){ // verifico se está vazio
   header('Location: cadastro1.php'); // se estiver vazio, redireciona para a 1ª página
}
?>

<form method="post" action="cadastro3.php">
   <strong>E-mail:</strong> <?php echo $email?>
   <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $email?>">
   ...
   resto dos campos do formulário
</form>
```

Nesta segunda página você já tem o e-mail do usuário armazenado na variável `$email`. No exemplo acima você pode criar um `input hidden` e preencher com o e-mail para ser enviado junto com o formulário.

- `cadastro3.php`

Nesta última página, você irá receber todos os campos enviados pelo formulário da página `cadastro2.php` e finalizar enviando para o banco de dados as informações.

---

Isto é apenas um esquema bem básico de como você poderia fazer. Claro que existem formas mais eficientes e enxutas para usuários mais avançados. Mas como a sua pergunta quer saber apenas como enviar um e-mail de uma página à outra, creio que isso possa lhe ajudar a ter a noção de como funciona.

Comment: Muito Obrigado, era isso mesmo que eu estava procurando, me ajudou a ter uma noção do que fazer!

Comment: Diego, finalize a pergunta marcando ✓ na resposta. Se houver dúvidas de como fazer isso, por favor nos informe.